# Concatenate rows of pd dataframe by category?

Tags: python, pandas

Alright, syntactically I dont know how to do this - I have a dataframe set up like this:

```
target   type    post
1      intj    "hello world shdjd"
2      entp    "hello world fddf"
16     estj   "hello world dsd"
4      esfp    "hello world sfs"
1      intj    "hello world ddfd"
```

where there are 16 `type`s that repeat for something like 10,000 rows. The posts are unique.

I need to concatenate all the posts that have the same `type` (or target - target is just the type number 1-16). Looked at [Pandas groupby category, rating, get top value from each category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880511/pandas-groupby-category-rating-get-top-value-from-each-category) and the `groupBy` method, however I dont know how to do this with strings.

Ive tried (dataframe is called `result`):

```
result = result.reset_index()
# print(result.loc[result.groupby('type').post.agg('idxmax')])
print(result.loc[result.groupby('type').post.str.cat(sep=' ')])
```

But neither work. How can I concatenate by same type?

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
target   type    post
    1      intj    "all intj posts concatenated .. "
    2      entp    "all entp posts concatenated .. "
    3      estj   "all estj  posts concatenated .. "
    4      esfp    "all esfp  posts concatenated .. "
    5      infj    "all infj posts concatenated .. "
    16     istj    "all istj posts concatenated .. "
```

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy check my edit - youll see there are now only 16 entries, with all of each type's posts concatenated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(df.groupby(by=['type', 'target'])['post'].agg(lambda col: ''.join(col)))

type  target
entp  2                          hello world fddf
esfp  4                           hello world sfs
estj  16                          hello world dsd
intj  1         hello world shdjdhello world ddfd
```

Comment: Thanks. In doing this, how can I count the number of posts for each type?

Comment: Do this `df.groupby(by=['type', 'target']).count()`

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick

```
df['post'] = df.groupby(['target','type'])['post'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x)).drop_duplicates()
```